# Document updating in couchbase

Tags: couchbase, sql++

In couchbase are updates implemented as **copies of the original record written out to a new location**, which likely requires updating of indexes as well OR are updates done in-place when only a few fields have changed on the document.

Answer (score 0):

Couchbase storage follows append-only storage model. Find more details at:
https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.6/architecture/storage-architecture.html